# Drupal VIews Exposed Filter: Taxonomy Select List?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-exposed-filter

Drupal 6: I have a view (version 2) with an exposed filter on taxonomy term name. The provided exposed widget is a text field with 'Apply' button. What I'm trying to do is to have a drop down populated from a specific vocabulary ('Provinces' vocab consisting of terms 'BC', 'AB', 'SK', etc.), not a free text field.

I thought once I expose the filter I would get the option for a select list, but I don't. All I get is 'Operator (Is equal to, Is not equal to, etc.)' - 'Value (blank field)' - 'optional (check box)'...

I thought that this would be a pretty common thing to do but all my google-ing has found no answer.

Anybody know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to expose the The *taxonomy term ID* not the The *taxonomy term name* in order to get the little gear icon so that you can get the drop-down.

Comment: Actually, no, I had not figured that one out yet... THANK YOU !!!! So simple once you know.

Answer (score 1):

I've using [better_exposed_filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters).
Click settings icon for exposed taxonomy filter and check "Dropdown list"!

[just add vocab and terms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyNAn.png)

Answer (score 0):

there are two areas where you can configure your taxonomy filter. First the "basic" settings, which include all settings you mentioned, and second the settings behind the "gear-icon", where you can chose your vocabbulary and the type of widget.

Comment: The problem is, I don't get a gear-icon when I add the exposed taxonomy to the filter. All I get is the 'basic' settings... any ideas as to why?